# Need help in finding my mistake in one fraction/percentage word problem

Tags: percentages, word-problem

Question : Jennifer has 40% more stamps than Peter. However, if she gives 45 of her stamps to Peter, then Peter will have 10% more stamps than Jennifer. How many stamps did Jennifer begin with ?

**Correct Solution below**:

- Initially Peter has $P$ stamps and Jennifer has $1.4P$
- Then; solving $P+45 = 1.1(1.4P-45)$ equation gives us P=175 and J=245.

I tried 2 solutions, both of my solutions gave me different result. I wish to understand the mistake i made in each of them. Most probably i have made mistake while creating the equation, but unable to find it as i feel my equation is right as per word problem.

***1st Approach***

- Initially Jennifer has $J$ stamps and Peter has $0.6J$ (because peter has 40% less stamps of Jennifer)
- Then; solving $0.60J+45=1.1(J-45)$ equation gives J=189 and P=113.4

$0.60J+45=1.1(J-45)$ // *when peter has 45 more stamps = 10% more stamps of jennifer*

$0.60J+45=1.1J-49.5$

$49.5+45=1.1J-0.60J$

$94.5=0.5J$

$J=189$ and $P=113.4$ after solving $0.6J$

***2nd Approach***
 - Initially Jennifer has $J$ stamps and Peter has $0.6J$
 - Then; solving $J-45=0.9(0.6J+45)$ equation gives J=185.86... & P=111.52...

$J-45=0.9(0.6J+45)$ // *when jennifer has 45 less stamps = 0.90% of peters stamp*

$J-45=0.54J+40.5$

$J-0.54J=45+40.5$

$0.46J=85.5$ which gives J=185.86... & P=111.52...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is at the first line.

If Jennifer has $J$. We have $J= 1.4P$, that is $P=\frac1{1.4}J \approx 0.714J$.  We do not have $P = 0.6J$.

When we say Jennifer has $40\%$ more stamps than Peter. View Peter having $100$ units of stamps while Jennifer has $140$ units. It is different from viewing Jennifer as having $100$ units and Peter having $60$ units.

Comment: But if Jennifer has 40% more stamps than peter, it also means peter has 40% less stamps than Jennifer, which is 60% of Jennifer stamps.

Comment: Why is it incorrect to view the reverse way. i.e consider Jennifer having 100 %/units and .... (what i mentioned above).

Comment: Sorry it may be silly to ask, but i wish to build my intuition around this kind of a problem

Comment: The notion of "unit" is different. Percentage refers to a proportion of a particular number that we view as a base. If you have $\$1$, and I have $50\%$ more than you, then I have $\$1.50$. However, consider the opposite now, how much is $\$1$ less than $\$1.50$ in terms of percentage?

Comment: Its $0.5 less which 33.333...% (0.5/1.5)

Comment: Yup, it's no longer $50\%$.

Comment: So i thought about it for some time... So when base are same only then we can do a switch. But if base are different (like in above case) its obviously incorrect to do.. Correct ?

Comment: yup, and the base is hardly the same... unless the difference is $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84565/discussion-between-lovewithmaths-and-siong-thye-goh).